# How to center multiple HTML UL lists

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with a a HTML UL list. See the following sample:
http://uploads.demaweb.dk/li.html

I would like the two menus to be displayed in on line and centered. How can I do that?

I'm not able to change anything inside the divs with the menu-class since they are generated by a CMS.

Comment: Can you clarify where you want the lists? It is not clear.

Comment: I'm sorry. This image shows how I would like it: http://uploads.demaweb.dk/li.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this... if I read the question correctly

Add `text-align:center;` to `.container`

and

`display:inline-block;` to `.menu`

```
  .container {
    width:800px;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    text-align:center;
  }

  .menu {
     margin:auto;
     display:inline-block;
  }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/8BAjV/

**EDIT**

> Your solution is almost working - except from situations where the
>   lists does not have the same height.

In that case, add `vertical-align:top;`

```
.menu {
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Revised example http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/8BAjV/2/

Comment: Your solution is almost working - except from situations where the lists does not have the same height. See this example: http://uploads.demaweb.dk/li2.html